# posting an image from a different url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm kind of stuck at the moment... I'm having an existing component here doing some basic image upload using an input type file and a multipart/form-data form. Ok... to be honest it's doing weird magic stuff with about 5 different javascripts in a html5 fancy way.

So I extended this component to use 3rd party images from a different server. But because of all that magic in the background there's some misbehavior. So I actually need to post the images to the server first and load the image from there. And no worries: the user is authenticated and it's his images hosted on a big social website.

Is there a way to read an image from a different server (x-domain) and post it to my server using FormData or something similar?

Comment: Could'nt you just link to it, like you'd normally do with external images ?

Comment: that's what I tried in the first step. but the admin component just doesn't work with those images as it's using svg afterwards. so it's doing so really odd stuff on the serverside...